# How to redirect to another page after making a POST request with jQuery ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, redirect, flask

On my web app I have a button that when clicked takes the values from some user input and posts it to a flask route.

```
$( "#button" ).click(function() {
  let data1 = // get data
  req = $.ajax({
              url: '/test',
              type: "POST",
              data: { data1: data1
                  }
            });
```

Here is the flask route:

```
@app.route('/test', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def testing():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.values.get('data1')
        # here I make some changes to data but it isn't important to question
        new_data = ...
        # I want to redirect to a new route with new_data
    else:
        # do something else...
```

How can I, after the post request, get redirected to a new route and still be able to access my new_data variable?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ajax **done** callback to redirect after the ajax call has finished:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/test',
    type: "POST",
    data: { data1: data1},
    done: function( serverResponseString) {
        window.location = serverResponseString;
    }
});
```

Comment: but the redirection happens on the server.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean, if your server creates the route you can return it from your server endpoint and use that in the callback .. see my edit

Comment: You are corrent, but I thought he may also want the redirection to happen only on the server, I posted an answer of how to redirect the call without the server returning the route as a response, but rather as a HTTP redirect..

Comment: Thanks for the answer I manage to adapt this to get the redirect to my new route but I don't know how to access `new_data` in my new route? How can I send that along with the redirect?

Comment: you can create an array/JSON Object on your server side for example `{url: "myURL", anotherValue: 'anotherValue'}`, return that and then access this in the done method like so `serverResponseString.url // 'myURL'`

Answer (score 0):

on flask:

`return redirect("http://www.example.com", code=302)`

on client - You cannot redirect to a page using ajax request, as you cannot get the redirection url.

What you may do is either use `fetch` api to get the redirection url: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/url

or If you insist on using `$.post`, you can pass your own custom `xhr` object, and retrieve the response's url from it.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
req = $.ajax({
    url: '/test',
    type: "POST",
    data: { 
        data1: data1
    },
    xhr: function() { return xhr; }
    success: function() { location.href = xhr.responseURL; } 
});
```

NOTICE:

Both methods wouldn't work in IE!

Comment: Thanks for the answer I manage to adapt this to get the redirect to my new route but I don't know how to access `new_data` in my new route? How can I send that along with the redirect?

Comment: send it like any response from the server, the redirect url is just a header you're accessing.

Comment: I don't understand sorry

Comment: You might want to create a new question for that, bacause it's not really related to the current question.

Comment: in my head it is the question I've been asking all along, clearly I'm too stupid to explain sorry for wasting your time :(